# How to set variable height to an updatable TextView from an Activity?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a table graphic made with TextView, whose data is updated from an Activity, but if I set the minimum height this is fine as long as the text is not longer in that case the text view does not stretch, probably because the text is updated after the view is created...

This is an image of result (see the last green line)
[image]

And this is the code:

```
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:minHeight="25dp"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"><TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtScNota"
    android:layout_below="@+id/xmlScUltima"
    android:layout_width="120dp"
    android:layout_height="25dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:background="@color/txtColSc"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:text=" Nota: "
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/xmlScNota"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtScNota"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtScNota"
    android:background="@color/xmlColSc"
    android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="25sp"
    android:paddingStart="3dp"
    android:paddingEnd="3dp"
    android:text="- - -"
```

Comment: make sure you are not using fixed height value in parent layout which contains this views, also post the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

Probably you're using a fixed height in the parent layout, or you're using wrap content.
If this is the case, it's also wrong because in one of the two TextViews you're using a fixed height, so the parent is inheriting that fixed height.

I don't know what are you using as parent layout but this is an example that should work

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:minHeight="25dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtScNota"
        android:layout_below="@+id/xmlScUltima"
        android:layout_width="120dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
        android:background="@color/txtColSc"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:text=" Nota: "
        android:textStyle="bold" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/xmlScNota"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/txtScNota"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="5dp"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/txtScNota"
        android:background="@color/xmlColSc"
        android:gravity="start|center_vertical"
        android:minHeight="25sp"
        android:paddingStart="3dp"
        android:paddingEnd="3dp"
        android:text="- - -"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: thanks, but unfortunately it doesn't work. As I said the problem is that the text is added / updated after the layout has already been created. In fact, if I try to put directly a long text in the box it works correctly, while if the long text 'comes later' doesn't work. I use a RelativeLayout

Answer (score 0):

Here are some hints:

1. Make sure your android:height="wrap_content"
2. Add attribute android:lines="2" (this enforces that your textview allows 2 lines, up to you to decide how many lines you should allow)
3. If things become messed up, check your Layout element, it might be better to use a gridlayout for this case or a constraintlayout to achieve what you want.